# Simple Loop query

Tags: loops

My brain obviously isn't firing on all cylinders but I was working on a program to discover if a number is prime number. The loop below works but I don't understand why. If the prime number(test[k]) is 5 and i = 3; why does the loop continue if 3 * 3 is > than 5?

```
        int [] test = new int[] {15,14,2,3,19,70,7,9,11,12,13,14,21,23,0,107};
int test2 = 7;


for(int k= 0; k <test.length; k++)
{
    boolean IsPrime= true;
    if(test[k]==2)
    {
        System.out.println(test[k] + " is a prime number");
        IsPrime = true;
        continue;
    }

    else if (test[k] % 2 == 0)
    {
        IsPrime = false;
        System.out.println(test[k] + " is NOT a prime number");
        continue;
    }

    else
        {
            for(int i = 3; i * i <= test[k]; i+= 2)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                if(test[k] % i == 0)
                {
                    IsPrime =false;
                }
            }
                if(IsPrime == true)
                System.out.println(test[k] + " is a prime number");

                else
                {
                    System.out.println(test[k] + " is NOT a prime number");
                }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have more code you could show us?

Comment: Yes.I was trying to perform the check more efficently by removing the even numbers from the loop and checking odd numbers up to the square root of the test number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop won't continue, it does work as expected.
Lets go though the code with test[k] = 5:

```
1) IsPrime = true (Line: 7)
2)  if (test[k] == 2) is false
3)  else if (test[k] % 2 == 0) is false
4)  we are in the else
4.1) i = 3
4.2) i*i <= 5 ? false
4.3) It does not go in the loop!
4.4) Is Prime == true is true;
--End--
```

Well where is the problem? Why do you think it does go in the loop?

Comment: Your absouletly correct. It was the layout of my code. I thought the IsPrime test was contained inside the loop instead of outside. Thank you. I thought i was forgetting about some side rule.